# linear transformation question. where did i go wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

i'm sorry if you can't read some parts so ask me if you need to know what it is but i really am confused as to what i did wrong.
Here is the picture of the question and answer that i gave:

http://gyazo.com/86a1f51019d505970f5aaa4941dd4f95

I wasn't given any feedback on this question so i really need help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix for $T_3$ is incorrect.  First off, it should be a $3\times 2$ matrix, since $T_3$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  And it should be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 2\\3&0\\-1&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You get the columns by evaluating $T_3$ on the two standard basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also when would it be a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: @user125535 The first number is the dimension of the range.  The second number is the dimension of the domain.  So, it would be $3\times 3$ when both the domain and range are $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: so basically, co-domain is the # of rows and domain is the # of columns?

Comment: @user125535 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to see it:

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be the matrices associated with $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively. Then

$$T_1(x)=A_1x$$
$$T_2(x)=A_2x$$

If $T_3(x)=T_1(T_2(x))=Ax$ then

$$T_3(x)=A_1A_2x$$

Hence, $A=A_1A_2$, where

$$
A_1=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & -1\\
   1 & 0 & 1\\
   -1 & 0 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
$$A_2=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
   2 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Comment: thats a neat way to think about it. But how would i know right away if it was a transformation from R2->R3. Like it would be 3x2? and R3->R4 would be 4x3?

Comment: Right, a linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ will have a matrix with as many columns as the dimension of $V$ and as many rows as the dimension of $W$.